# Apache HttpClient 5 and JDK16- NoHttpResponseException

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-httpclient-5.x

In the last 15 days we have sent about 8,000,000 requests using Apache HttpClient 5. The problem is that 81,000 of the 8,000,000 requests failed and cause a NoHttpResponseException. To solve the problems we have already updated to a new JDK and frequently close all idle connections.The requests go to different destinations which in some cases receive the packets despite the exception.

Have any of you had a similar problem and already found a solution for it?

On our Systems we are currently using:

- Apache Tomcat 9.0.31 (Debian)
- Amazon Corretto 16.0.1.9.1
- org.apache.httpcomponents.core5:httpcore5 5.0.3,
- org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5 5.0.3

Comment: I would start by looking at the NoHttpResponseException’s stack trace.  It’s probably caused by a communication exception, for instance a SocketException.